# Windows Phone Develoment – Multiple .mp3 files in media element and sound-effect not working

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi,

I am developing few sound related things in one project but facing some difficulties. 
Basically I want to have one .mp3 sound playing as back ground. However, when some event is fired, I want to run other .mp3 sound-effect. That means together, both .mp3 sound will run in a project.

I have found something where .WAV playing in background and also on other events, but this increases size of an application.

Can I put .mp3 sounds at both locatoins?

Following is code to play back ground music:

```
FCbackgroundsound = new MediaElement();
FCbackgroundsound.AutoPlay = true;
FCbackgroundsound.Source = new Uri("Resources/FCbackgroundsound.wav", UriKind.Relative);
FCbackgroundsound.Volume = 0.8f;
FCbackgroundsound.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(ambienceSound_MediaEnded);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(FCbackgroundsound);
FCbackgroundsound.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

When I put .mp3, it is not running and giving error.

So once this runs, I want to play some .mp3 sounds based on some events.

Can anyone please guide or help in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone please provide an update on this? I am really stuck and trying from some days now. Can't i include multiple mp3 within same project? This should work since this is very standard format.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually you can not play the sound files keeping as resource files.
This is cause for the media playback to not to start.**

You have to copy the **resource sound files to the IsolatedStorage** .

**and then you need to set the same files as source to the MediaElement** to start the media playback.

[you can refer this link for to know how to copy the resource media files to IsolatedStorage programmatically and play from there.](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Binary-files)

Comment: Hi Santhu, I see the point. However, i want something where one mp3 files is running in back ground and on some click event second mp3 file runs. Means running 2 or more mp3 files Simultaneous. 

Can we achieve this with all mp3 or do i need to go for all wav files?

Comment: Hi David, did you tried by using multiple media Elements, for playing files simultaneously.

Comment: Hi Santhu, as per my research and knowledge... it is allowing maximum 2 mp3 but that too are not getting played simultaneously. I need both 1) playing more then 2 mp3 2) playing them simultaneously... can i do this and if so.. can u please guide me?